# Error in getaddrinfo when host name contains character "\032"

Tags: networking, dns

Hosts resolution is failing when host name to resold contains the character "**\032**"
The bad thing is that it works well in most devices I have but my laptop :(

My laptop has ubuntu focal.

```
dig something.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> something.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8706
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;something.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
something.com.  3600    IN  CNAME   \032somethingmore.azure.com.
\032somethingmore.azure.com.    10 IN A **.**.**.**

;; Query time: 160 msec
;; SERVER: 80.58.61.250#53(80.58.61.250)
;; WHEN: mar nov 10 19:08:16 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128

ping something.com
ping: something.com: System Error

dig +short AAAA something.com
\032somethingmore.azure.com

nc -zv -4 something.com 443
nc: getaddrinfo for host "something.com" port 443: No address associated with hostname
```

The only half-success I had was changing /etc/nsswitch.conf :

```
-hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

+hosts:          dns files


nc -zv something.com 443
nc: getaddrinfo for host "something.com" port 443: Name or service not known

ping something.com
ping: something.com: Name or service not known
```

But it is still invalid for me...

Thanks in advance.

Victor.

I found a link that might be of interest:

Incorrect handling of records with "\032" in the label

https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/issues/345

Comment: The characters allowed in hostnames are traditionally restricted to a-z, 0-9 and - (hypen) ... later some special handling of national special characters has been added - but still only printable characters, What do you expect \032 to be ?

Comment: I'm not interested in \032 character specially, but since dns servers can return it in the middle of a name maybe it should be accepted by ping and getaddrinfo. 
Although I can see your point of view: why do we need it?